# Why OrderModify() returns a code-error 130?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I have an order modification code for my open market orders which comes up with **`Error 130`** in the `MT4` Journal, I know this is an age-old issue & there are several sources I have looked at, both here & throughout the web - however, nothing seems to work.

1) I have **`NormalizeDouble()`**-cured everything that has double functions on `MQL4` i.e prices etc - this is to ensure that the number of digits after the decimal points are consistent with the pair its trading; some are 3 digits, others are 5 digits.

2) The `pnlPoints` & `stopPoints` are calculated using the **`_Period`** so the number of points are consistent regardless of the number of digits after the decimal point of the chart the EA is dropped on

3) I'm aware of the presence of the **`MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL )`** & haved added this to the **`MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_SPREAD )`** to some to the **`stoplevel`** calculation.

4) I want 100 points "In the money" before the order is modified to breakeven.

5) I'm using a five digit broker but as you will know, some pairs like the **`EURJPY`** will have three digits. This is corrected by the **`_Period`** & the **`NormalizeDouble()`** funtions.

```
                 /*Breakeven Order Modification*/
                 for(int b = OrdersTotal()-1;b>=0;b--)
                 {
                 if(OrderSelect(b,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==true)
                    {
                    double   aBidPrice   =  MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_BID);
                    double   anOpenPrice =  OrderOpenPrice();
                    double   aNewTpPrice =  OrderTakeProfit();
                    double   aCurrentSL  =  OrderStopLoss();
                    double   aNewSLPrice =  anOpenPrice;
                    double   pnlPoints   =  NormalizeDouble(aBidPrice - anOpenPrice/_Point,Digits);
                    double   stopPoints  =  NormalizeDouble(aBidPrice - aNewSLPrice/_Point,Digits);
                    int      stopLevel   =  int(MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_STOPLEVEL)+MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_SPREAD));
                    int      aTicket     =  OrderTicket();
                    if(OrderType() == OP_BUY)
                    if(stopPoints > stopLevel)
                    if(aTicket > 0)
                    if(pnlPoints > breakeven)
                    if(aNewSLPrice == aCurrentSL)continue;
                       {
                       BuyMod = OrderModify(OrderTicket(),NormalizeDouble(anOpenPrice,Digits),NormalizeDouble(aNewSLPrice,Digits),NormalizeDouble(aNewTpPrice,Digits),0,buycolor);
                       SendMail("Notification of Order Modification for Ticket#"+IntegerToString(OrderTicket(),10),"Good news! Order Ticket#"+IntegerToString(OrderTicket(),10)+"has been changed to breakeven");
                       if(BuyMod = false || aTicket == 0)
                          {
                          Print("Order modification for ticket #"+IntegerToString(aTicket,10)+"Error code",GetLastError());
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
                 for(int s = OrdersTotal()-1; s>=0; s--)
                    {
                    if(OrderSelect(s,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==true)
                       {
                       double   anAskPrice  =  MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_ASK);
                       double   anOpenPrice =  OrderOpenPrice();
                       double   aNewTpPrice =  OrderTakeProfit();
                       double   aCurrentSL  =  OrderStopLoss();
                       double   aNewSLPrice =  anOpenPrice;
                       double   pnlPoints   =  NormalizeDouble(anOpenPrice - anAskPrice/_Point,Digits);
                       double   stopPoints  =  NormalizeDouble(aNewSLPrice - anAskPrice/_Point,Digits);
                       int      stopLevel   =  int(MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_STOPLEVEL)+MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_SPREAD));
                       int      aTicket     =  OrderTicket();
                       if(OrderType()== OP_SELL)
                       if(stopPoints > stopLevel)
                       if(aTicket > 0)
                       if(pnlPoints > breakeven)
                       if(aNewSLPrice == aCurrentSL)continue;
                          {
                          SellMod = OrderModify(OrderTicket(),NormalizeDouble(anOpenPrice,Digits),NormalizeDouble(aNewSLPrice,Digits),NormalizeDouble(aNewTpPrice,Digits),0,sellcolor);
                          SendMail("Notification of Order Modification for Ticket#"+IntegerToString(OrderTicket(),10),"Good news! Order Ticket#"+IntegerToString(OrderTicket(),10)+"has been changed to breakeven");
                          if(SellMod = false || aTicket == 0)
                             {
                             Print("Order modification for ticket #"+IntegerToString(aTicket,10)+"Error code",GetLastError());
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }
```

Many thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `MQL4` Error `130` stands for **`ERR_INVALID_STOPS`**

So the next best step is to review your `OrderModify()` calls, adding a self-journalling of the actual values, that are to be put inside the Server-side sent instruction.

Design a wrapper function, with an exactly the same calling-signature as standard `OrderModify()` has:

```
int LogAndSendOrderModify( int      const aTicketNUMBER,
                           double   const anOrderOpenPRICE,
                           double   const aStopLossPRICE,
                           double   const aTakeProfitPRICE,
                           datetime const anExpirationTIME,
                           color    const aMarkerArrowCOLOR
                           ){ ... }
```

... and include a piece of code, right before the `OrderModify()`, which exactly logs each value into a journal.

```
PrintFormat( "[%s]: TKT:[%d]OP:[%15.8f]SL:[%15.8f]TP:[%15.8f]SL_STOPZONE:[%d]TP_STOPZONE:[%d]SL_FREEZEZONE:[T.B.D.]TP_FREEZEZONE:[T.B.D.]",
              __FUNCTION__,
              aTicketNUMBER,
              anOrderOpenPRICE,
              aStopLossPRICE,
              aTakeProfitPRICE,
              (int) ( MathPow( 10, _Digits ) * ( Bid - aStopLossPRICE ) ),
              (int) ( MathPow( 10, _Digits ) * ( aTakeProfitPRICE - Bid ) )
              );
```

For **`??_FREEZEZONE`** you need to provide values similarly, but with a need to call an `OrderSelect( aTicketNUMBER, ... )` accordingly, before making any request into a current state of the `db.Pool` records with `{ OrderTakeProfit() | OrderStopLoss() }`, but the principle is obvious.

**Facts matter** and if self-reported values are compliant with Broker Terms& Condition and still keep getting `ERR_INVALID_STOPS`, **ask your Broker for a due explanation of any non-compliance observed.**

Comment: Excellent, sounds good. Would this work on backtesting as well?

Comment: Glad you have found this usefull. `PrintFormat()` works fine in StrategyTester ( suppressed only in optimisation mode, check the Help file  )

Comment: That's great, & where would you put the int LogAndSendOrderModify code in the EA. Further, I get that in the **%15.8f**, that the 8 Is the number of decimal places after the point, but what does the "15" determine?

Comment: For details check the HELP file. %15.8f stands as inline formatter of a **f** loat number, **15** digits wide placeholder, with **8** digits after decimal point. Old-good-FORTRAN :o)

Comment: Yep, that makes sense as well, 15 being the max number of digits in the placeholder, what you the LogAndSendOrderModify, where would that go?

Comment: Simply wherever you planned to use the `OrderModify()`. This is the very concept of wrappers.

Comment: Just a quick questions, the information on the LogAndSendOrderModify; could values from the Order Select function be plugged into the printf section where there is currently the data after the __FUNCTION__? Also what goes into the the {...} bit of your code?

Comment: Just a quick answer. Wrappers are used to be used a slim-jacket around the original function, the `OrderModify()` in this case. So a simplest ever design has no magic inside **`int LogAndSendOrderModify( ... ){ PrintFormat( ...);return( OrderModify( ... ) );`** and all parameters are the same as for a **naked `OrderModify()`** call, but transferred instead "through" the wrapper's defined function-call formal parameters, thus allowing them to be both logged and re-inserted into the wrapped-in naked `OrderModify()` call ). So easy, so simple.